# parsing datetime but dt is changing the day from 8th to 7th?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(value)

Where my value = {3/8/2011 12:00:00 AM}

but dt is showing dt = {3/7/2011 12:00:00 AM}

Please shed some light as I am about to pull my hair.

**EDIT:** Code OP posted as a comment:

```
foreach (SPField field in contentType.Fields)
{
    string fValue;
    object value = spitem[field.Id];
    if (value is DateTime)
    {
        DateTime dateField = DateTime.Parse(field.GetFieldValueAsHtml(value));
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(field.GetFieldValueAsText(value), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        fValue = dt.ToShortDateString();
        lblMetaData.Text += field + ": " + fValue + "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        fValue = field.GetFieldValueForEdit(value);
        lblMetaData.Text += field + ": " + fValue + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please add the **exact** code that fails to your question.

Comment: This is simply not possible. There is something more subtle going on that we don't know about.

Comment: The posted info isn't very accurate.  The debugger never shows a string with braces like that, it uses double-quotes.  Post a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My gut tells me there is a typo in the code. There is probably a missing an assignment.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("3/7/2011 12:00:00 AM");
....
DateTime.Parse("3/8/2011 12:00:00 AM"); //Parse's return is being ignored
....
dt is still {3/7/2011 12:00:00 AM}
```

Make sure the call to `DateTime.Parse("3/8/2011 12:00:00 AM");` is being assigned to `dt`.

---

Based on your edit I feel like your code would be better like this, however the posted code should still work.

```
foreach (SPField field in contentType.Fields) 
{ 
    string fValue;
    object value = spitem[field.Id]; 

    if (value is DateTime) 
    { 
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;
        fValue = dt.ToShortDateString(); 
        lblMetaData.Text += field + ": " + fValue + "\r\n";
    } 
    else 
    {         
        fValue = field.GetFieldValueForEdit(value); 
        lblMetaData.Text += field + ": " + fValue + "\r\n"; 
    }  
}
```

Comment: what are you saying. Datetime dt = Datetime.Parse(value). The value is this case is 3/8/2011 12:00:00 AM. so dt should be 3/8/2011 NOT 3/7/2011

Comment: this line did the magic. DateTime dt = (DateTime)value; Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your problem. The following code works for me, no change in the day part:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("3/8/2011 12:00:00 AM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")); 
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2011, 3, 8), dt);
```

Please try to post actual code that reproduces your problem.

UPDATE:
Now that you posted some code, I can say the following:
Your code doesn't seem to make sense. Why?
Because your code will only execute the `if` clause, if value is a `DateTime`. But in that case, you first somehow convert it to a text with `GetFieldValueAsText` and parse that text back into a `DateTime`. Just use the `value` directly.
Anyhow, even with that strange code, it should work, if `field.GetFieldValueAsText(value)` would work correctly, which I doubt it does. Did you check that it indeed returns the correct string?

Comment: I dont have var (using .net 2.0). Also, I dont see cultureinfo. I only see CultureInfoConverter.

Comment: I added globalization and now see CultureInfo but it didnt work.

Comment: @Madhu: I changed the code. For `CultureInfo`, add this to the top of your cs file: `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: @Madhu: What don't you understand in the following sentence: *"Post some code"*

Comment: Why are you reparsing it if it is a `DateTime`? Why not just cast it when you are in the true banch of the `if` DateTime dt = (DateTime)value;

Comment: @Daniel: I did some print shots and links are posted back to original post.

Comment: @Bob. I am not reparsing. Just created a new instance. I will do the cleanup later.

Comment: @Madhu: Yes, you **do** reparse it! Exactly in the line the debugger is at in your first screenshot.

Comment: @Everyone - Thanks for all your help and putting up me. Bob's solution helped me. Thanks all again.

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` will always have a time, but you don't have to do anything with it. For instance, if you need to display a `DateTime` back to a user, just don't show the time:

```
var display = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Stop everyone. I dont care about the time. Look at the actual date. I am feeding 3/8/2011 (March 8th, 2011) but result is 3/7/2011 (march 7th, 2011)

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` data type stores both a date and time. There is no way to change this.

If you want to change the way the date appears when you display it, just format it to display only the date. For example, use `dt.ToString("D");` or `dt.ToShortDateString();`.

Comment: Stop everyone. I dont care about the time. Look at the actual date. I am feeding 3/8/2011 (March 8th, 2011) but result is 3/7/2011 (march 7th, 2011)

Comment: @Madhu: Perhaps you didn't choose a very good subject for this question then. If it's reading a different date, please post your code. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime structure represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and **time** of day.

If you want the time portion only you can select 
dt.ToShortTimeString();

Comment: Stop everyone. I dont care about the time. Look at the actual date. I am feeding 3/8/2011 (March 8th, 2011) but result is 3/7/2011 (march 7th, 2011)